# Azure server - SQL server connection issue

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have hosted application on window azure server. My database instance is also on window azure.

Sometime (not always) I am getting following error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - An operation on a socket could not be performed
>   because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue
>   was full.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An operation on
>   a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient
>   buffer space or because a queue was full    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---

Could you please advice, why I am getting this error only some time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making lots (and *lots*) of connections to the database? And if so, do you gracefully dispose of them as soon as you're done? And is DI involved? Do you use EF or some other OR mapper, or are you just connecting through ADO.NET? As you see there are quite some questions you could answer to help us give you an answer...

You should always prepare for Azure SQL (or actually any Azure component) to not be available, for instance by implementing a retry mechanism. Find the one appropriate for your scenario in the [Retry service specific guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific) document. An interesting search term for this is [Transient Fault Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/transient-faults).

Comment: Thanks @Rick van den Bosch , I am using EF. And I am getting this error sometime not always.